# Wait until Angular Observable is "Complete"

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

Looked around and nothing I found quite fit my problem. How can I make the rest of `.ts` code to wait for an observable to finish.

I'm new to Angular and still trying to figure out how `Observables` work. I'm familiar with using them in my templates with `| async` but using them to get data in my `.ts` files isn't working how I expected.

I want everything to wait for the `Observable` to complete before moving on. My goal here is to set the class variable `briefed` based on the response of my observable.

I'm going to be using that variable

Unfortunately, the briefing variable never changes. I'm positive this is a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

My class essentially boils down to:

```
export class briefValidatorComponent implements OnInit{
    briefed: boolean = false;
    output: customObjectTwo;

    @Input() inputOne: customObject;
    @Input() inputTwo: customObject;

    ngOnIt(){
        this.userService
            .getBriefingReflectedForUser()
            .subscribe(response => {
                this.briefed = response.briefingInCasport; //Returns true
                console.log(this.briefed); //Prints true
            });

        console.log(this.briefed); //Prints false

        functionOne(objectOne, objectTwo);
    }

    functionOne(objectOne, objectTwo){
        //does some work with the briefed variable to 
        //determine what the output will be
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, should have been more complete with my intent. Haven't written the rest of the code yet because I got stumped here.

I'll have another function that evaluate some input data to determine what the output will be. I'll then reference that output in my DOM to change what will be shown there.

I looked into doing all the work in the subscribe method but I wouldn't be able to then change the output for the DOM to reference.

Comment: You don't wait. You need to deal with the fact that the data may not initially be available, or use a resolver to hold the component loading until it is.

Comment: the fact that you're asking this question actually shows you understand the concept perfectly. this is how asynchronous functions work in javascript. that said, you can use native `async\await` functions to get the behavior you're after. but if using angular i'd stick with observables.

Comment: `I want everything to wait for the Observable to complete before moving on`. If grandma has to wait until your Observable completes to put a cup of tea on we're going to have problems. No, but seriously do you want something in your component template (HTML) to wait to load or do you want some other logical code in your component to wait, can you be more specific than "everything?"

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I edited my post to hopefully be more clear with my intent. To briefly sum it up. I want to be able to do work to change a variable that will be used to determine what is shown in the dom.

Comment: Subscription is kind of callback, the whole idea it doesn't block. You'll have to call `functionOne()` inside subscription block or use it's third param: `.subscribe(response => console.log(response), errors => {}, () => this.functionOne())`. There's (https://learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html) `finalize` operator for pipe is available as well which works the same